# Authenticating with OAuth2 in a Durandal single page application

Tags: knockout.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, requirejs, durandal

I have a single page application which uses Durandal. On one of the pages I need to authenticate with OAuth 2 to get a token which I use to call a web service. I do not want to loose my single page application state, so I would like to perform OAuth authorization in a new window.

The unsolved problem which I have now is passing OAuth token from the child window to the parent. I tried to find a way to put the token from the child window to the Durandal app in the parent window, but I have not found any solution. Finally I decided just to put it in a property of the parent window, but it still does not work.

Here is my module code:

```
activate: function () {
    var authTokenDeffered = $.Deferred();

    if (!window.myAuthToken) {
        var authWindow = window.open(
            "https://oauth.myprovider.com/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=98599205d0aa4837a074cc19163bd38e&display=popup",
            "_blank", "modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");

        var checkConnect = setInterval(function () {
            if (!authWindow || !authWindow.closed) return;
            clearInterval(checkConnect);

            // I expect token here, but I do not get it
            console.log(window.myAuthToken); 

            authTokenDeffered.resolve(window.myAuthToken);
        }, 100);
    } else {
        authTokenDeffered.resolve(window.myAuthToken)
    }

    var campaigns = this.campaigns;
    return authTokenDeffered.then(function (authToken) {
        http.get('https://myprovider.com/my-service', {}, {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken})
            .then(function (response) { campaigns(response); });
    });
},
```

The OAuth 2 callback page has the following script:

```
var token = /access_token=([0-9a-f]+)/.exec(document.location.hash)[1];
window.parent.myAuthToken = token;
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to pass data to parent is

```
window.opener.myAuthToken = token;
```